# Does Terraform allow overriding resources from modules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a Terraform module where I wanted to refactor the EFS so it is managed in the module rather than in the Terraform I presently have.  Presently my Terraform includes two VPCs sharing an EFS using VPC Peering connection.

Eventually I want to be rid of *old* VPC but the EFS is still held by the *old* VPC.  EFS does not allow creating `aws_efs_mount_target` on a different VPC.

```
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "main" {
  for_each = toset(module.docker-swarm.subnets)

  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.main.id
  subnet_id = each.key
}
```

So I was wondering, is it possible to set something along the lines of

```
disable {
  module.common.aws_efs_mount_target.main 
}
```

or

```
module "common" {

  exclude = [ "aws_efs_mount_target.main " ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.  Basically create a new variable and use that as a condition to make an empty set.

```
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "main" {

  for_each = var.skip_efs_mount_target ? [] : toset(module.docker-swarm.subnets)

  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.main.id
  subnet_id = each.key
}
```